# Wordpress does not execute wp_head()

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress does not execute wp_head(). In the file function.php I prescribe the connection of the style, but it is not executed.

INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  
  <!-- wp_head(); -->
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

FUNCTION.PHP

```
<?php

function wp_head_link_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_head_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . './assets/css/style.css');



    // wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_head_link_style' ); // хук автоматом сработает во время wp_head

?>
```

I tried to look through with "Query Monitor", but it doesn't complain

Answer (score 0):

You have entered the wrong path for the stylesheet. (**'./assets/css/style.css'**)

Try this in your **functions.php** file:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_head_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css');
```

Whether your problem is resolved or not, please let me know.

Comment: No, don't worked :(